# Please use override option or check for definition, koin android?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I am implementing Koin DI in my android application. I was successfully able to create some of the modules. However I got an exception where I tried to get object from another in module.

These are my modules

```
val networkModule = module {
factory { provideRetrofit() }

single { provideNetworkApi(get()) }
}


fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
return Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(NetworkConstant.BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(
        GsonConverterFactory.create(
            GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                .create()
        )
    )
    .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
    .build()

 }

fun provideNetworkApi(retrofit: Retrofit): NetworkCall =
retrofit.create(NetworkCall::class.java)
```

view model module - i want to pass the network call object here

```
val viewModelModule = module {
single { provideNetworkApi(get ()) }
}
```

This is my code in application class

```
startKoin {
        androidLogger()
        androidContext(this@BaseApp)
        modules(listOf(networkModule,viewModelModule))
    }
```

This is the exception I get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.mountmeru.BaseApp: org.koin.core.error.DefinitionOverrideException: Definition '[Factory:'com.mountmeru.network.NetworkCall']' try to override existing definition. Please use override option or check for definition '[Factory:'com.mountmeru.network.NetworkCall']'
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6465)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: org.koin.core.error.DefinitionOverrideException: Definition '[Factory:'com.mountmeru.network.NetworkCall']' try to override existing definition. Please use override option or check for definition '[Factory:'com.mountmeru.network.NetworkCall']'
    at org.koin.core.scope.ScopeDefinition.save(ScopeDefinition.kt:25)
```

Any clue whats wrong here?

Comment: replace `single { provideNetworkApi(get ()) }` to  
`single {provideNetworkApi(provideRetrofit()) }` and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing it all wrong. The correct implementation is

I wanted the `NetworkCall` object in my `LoginViewModel`

```
val viewModelModule = module {
single { LoginViewModel(get()) }
}
```

And the viewmodel class is follows

```
class LoginViewModel(val networkCall: NetworkCall) : ViewModel(){

}
```

So far I feel koin is quite good

Answer (score 10):

For anyone else dealing with this error message, `Koin` disallows any ambiguity in its modules. So if you try to load one bean definition that conforms to the same signature as one that has already been loaded, you end up getting this error. If your intention is to replace the old definition with a new one, then use the `override` flag.

Here is a usage example:

```
loadKoinModules(
  module(override = true) {
    single<A> {
      A
    }
  }
)
```